# How would I log the hash values in this API response?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and I was wondering how I would access the hash value and return the string so I can log it? Here's my code, I'm using axios.

Here's my code:

```
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ')
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
   
    if (command === 'search') {
        let termargs = args.join(" ");
        
        const options = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://breachdirectory.p.rapidapi.com/',
            params: { func: 'auto', term: termargs},
            headers: {
                'x-rapidapi-host': 'breachdirectory.p.rapidapi.com',
                'x-rapidapi-key': (keytouse, keys[keytouse]),
            }
        };
        message.reply("searching...")
        options.params.term = termargs
        


        axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
            
            console.log('Found:' , response.data["result"]);
        }).catch(function (error) {
           message.reply(JSON.stringify(error));
        });
    }

        
});



client.login(TOKEN);
```

Here's what it returns:

```
Found: 

    [
      { has_password: false, sources: [ 'Pluto.tv' ] },
      {
        has_password: true,
        password: 'bleh',
        hash: 'kMUX9351bsMjbgXH9rpKKf+GIYJrJy4=',
        sources: [ 'Aptoide.com' ]
      },
      {
        has_password: true,
        password: 'blah',
        hash: 'lEiyXSecP9cIGJfyYhs8yteVEplUIRjAvaI7Jc76upI=',
        sources: [ 'Collection 1' ]
      },
      {
        has_password: true,
        password: 'blahblahblah',
        hash: 'djdrICyb/EfH6+R0g/26+d+GIYJrJy6j',
        sources: 'Unverified'
      }
    ]
```

I tried doing response.data.results.hash but that didn't work. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: This is probably very advanced given the fact I literally just started javascript yesterday, but I can kind of understand it cause I used to code in a similar language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the results is an array so :

```
response.data.results[i].hash
```

that "i" is a number like 0,1,...

Answer (score 0):

The response seems to be an array of objects, so maybe try looping throw the response and get the hash of each object. E.G:

```js
axios.get('/user?ID=12345')
  .then(function (response) {
    response.data.forEach(item => {
      console.log(item.hash);
    });
  })
```

If this doesn't work could you please share a console.log() of the response object?

The axios GET example was recover